# How Do I Call An Authenticated HTTP Trigger Google Cloud Function Via A Next.js (with Typescript) App?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, next.js, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication

I created a Google Cloud Platform account, and made a simple hello_world type Python "Cloud Function" that just spits out some simple text. I made this function "HTTP" accessible and only able to be called/authenticated by a "Service Account" that I made for the purpose of calling this very function. I generated a key for this "Service Account" and downloaded the json file for the key.

The problem is that I can't find any documentation on how to call this function with my service account in a next.js app. I tried this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { GoogleAuth } from 'google-auth-library';

const projectId = 'gtwitone';
const keyFilename = '/Users/<myusername>/path/to/cloudfunction/credentials.json';

class Middle extends React.Component {
    handleClick() {
        console.log('this is:', this);
      }
    // This syntax ensures `this` is bound within handleClick.  // Warning: this is *experimental* syntax.  handleClick = () => {    console.log('this is:', this);  }

    /* async listFunctions() {
        const [functions] = await client.listFunctions();
        console.info(functions);
    } */

    async runGoogleCloudFunctionTest() {
      // Define your URL, here with Cloud Run but the security is exactly the same with Cloud Functions (same underlying infrastructure)
      const url = "https://us-central1-<projectname>.cloudfunctions.net/<functionname>"
      //Example with the key file, not recommended on GCP environment.
      const auth = new GoogleAuth({keyFilename: keyFilename})
  
      //Create your client with an Identity token.
      const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(url);
      const res = await client.request({url});
      console.log(res.data);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
            <Button variant='primary' onClick={this.runGoogleCloudFunctionTest}>
                Click me
            </Button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default Middle;
```

But I got this error in my terminal:

```
<myusername>@<mycomputername> <thisnextjsappdirectory> % yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.17
$ next dev
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 267 ms (124 modules)
wait  - compiling / (client and server)...
wait  - compiling...
error - ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:17:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js
./components/Middle.tsx
./pages/index.tsx

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
Native Node.js APIs are not supported in the Edge Runtime. Found `child_process` imported.

Could not find files for / in .next/build-manifest.json
Could not find files for / in .next/build-manifest.json
^C
<myusername>@<mycomputername> <thisnextjsappdirectory> %
```

I know that this is problem with server side rendering in my Next.js app and people recommend using a client side package like this https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client. But `google-api-javascript-client` doesn't have any documentation on authenticating with a `.json` credentials file instead of an `API KEY` which I do not have.

In short how do I get my app to work and run the Google Cloud function with a `.json` credentials file for am authenticated service account?

Comment: Can you check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#exchanging_a_self-signed_jwt_for_a_google-signed_id_token) if this helps you?

Comment: Hi. Did it solve your issue? Else we can see where you are getting stuck and we can work on it. Please respond if the issue is solved on your end or not.

Comment: Yes, I just posted an answer that worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by simply moving the `GoogleAuth` api call to the `pages/api` route.

pages/api/google.ts

```
// Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"
import { GoogleAuth } from "google-auth-library"

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<any>) {
    const url = process.env.FUNCTION_URL as string

    //Example with the key file, not recommended on GCP environment.
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({ keyFilename: process.env.KEYSTORE_PATH })

    //Create your client with an Identity token.
    const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(url)
    const result = await client.request({ url })
    console.log(result.data)
    res.json({ data: result.data })
}
```

components/Middle.tsx

```
import React from "react"
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap"

class Middle extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
        console.log("this is:", this)
    }
  
  // this talks with /pages/api/google
  async imCallingAnAPI() {
    const result = await fetch("/api/google")
    console.log({ result })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.imCallingAnAPI}>
          Click me
        </Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Middle
```

pages/index.tsx

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Header from '../components/Header';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import Middle from '../components/Middle';

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <><main className='d-flex flex-column min-vh-100'>
      <Header />
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <Middle />
      </main>
      <footer>
        <Footer />
      </footer>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

I think that next.js has trouble loading `GoogleAuth` in a component. I'm not 100% sure why, but I think it has to do with next.js not knowing exactly how to handle `GoogleAuth` with server-side rendering.